# How i can get img-element and text into span-block?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have span block like this:

```html
<span class="selectable-text invisible-space copyable-text" dir="ltr">
     some text
     <img alt="" class="b61 emoji wa selectable-text invisible-space copyable-text" data-plain-text="" src="URL" style="background-position: -20px -20px;"/>
     more some text
     <img alt="" class="b62 emoji wa selectable-text invisible-space copyable-text" data-plain-text="" src="URL" style="background-position: -40px -40px;"/>
     blah-blah-blah
     <img alt="" class="b76 emoji wa selectable-text invisible-space copyable-text" data-plain-text="" src="URL" style="background-position: 0px -20px;"/>
</span>
```

```py
soup.find('span', {'class': 'selectable-text invisible-space copyable-text'}).get_text()
```

This code give me only the text.

Everything i've thought of

```py
span = soup.select('span', {'class': 'selectable-text invisible-space copyable-text'})
for item in span:
    if re.match('.*emoji', str(item)):
        ...
```

Now i have the string like this:

```html
<span class="selectable-text invisible-space copyable-text" dir="ltr">some text <img alt="" class="b61 emoji wa selectable-text invisible-space copyable-text" data-plain-text="" src="URL" style="background-position: -20px -20px;"/>more some text<img alt="" class="b62 emoji wa selectable-text invisible-space copyable-text" data-plain-text="" src="URL" style="background-position: -40px -40px;"/> blah-blah-blah  <img alt="" class="b76 emoji wa selectable-text invisible-space copyable-text" data-plain-text="" src="URL" style="background-position: 0px -20px;"/></span>
```

The next step, it seems to me, is to use the regular expressions to get the elements I need.

Is there any other way to get a string like:

```
some text <emoji> more some text <emoji> blah-blah-blah <emoji>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find Children inside `Span` tag and then use `previous_element` which is text value.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
data='''<span class="selectable-text invisible-space copyable-text" dir="ltr">
     some text
     <img alt="" class="b61 emoji wa selectable-text invisible-space copyable-text" data-plain-text="" src="URL" style="background-position: -20px -20px;"/>
     more some text
     <img alt="" class="b62 emoji wa selectable-text invisible-space copyable-text" data-plain-text="" src="URL" style="background-position: -40px -40px;"/>
     blah-blah-blah
     <img alt="" class="b76 emoji wa selectable-text invisible-space copyable-text" data-plain-text="" src="URL" style="background-position: 0px -20px;"/>
</span>'''

soup=BeautifulSoup(data,'html.parser')
itemtag=soup.find('span', class_='selectable-text invisible-space copyable-text')
children = itemtag.findChildren()
items=[]
for child in children:
  items.append(child.previous_element.replace('\n','').strip())
  items.append(child)

print(items)
```

Output:

```
['some text', <img alt="" class="b61 emoji wa selectable-text invisible-space copyable-text" data-plain-text="" src="URL" style="background-position: -20px -20px;"/>, 'more some text', <img alt="" class="b62 emoji wa selectable-text invisible-space copyable-text" data-plain-text="" src="URL" style="background-position: -40px -40px;"/>, 'blah-blah-blah', <img alt="" class="b76 emoji wa selectable-text invisible-space copyable-text" data-plain-text="" src="URL" style="background-position: 0px -20px;"/>]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract text and img into a span then the below code should work.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

stra = """
<span class="selectable-text invisible-space copyable-text" dir="ltr">
     some text
     <img alt="" class="b61 emoji wa selectable-text invisible-space copyable-text" data-plain-text="" src="URL" style="background-position: -20px -20px;"/>
     more some text
     <img alt="" class="b62 emoji wa selectable-text invisible-space copyable-text" data-plain-text="" src="URL" style="background-position: -40px -40px;"/>
     blah-blah-blah
     <img alt="" class="b76 emoji wa selectable-text invisible-space copyable-text" data-plain-text="" src="URL" style="background-position: 0px -20px;"/>
</span>
"""
soup = bs(stra, 'html.parser')

ch = list(soup.find('span', {'class': 'selectable-text invisible-space copyable-text'}).children)

for i in zip(ch[::2], ch[1::2]):
    print('<span>{}{}</span>'.format(*i))
```

Output:

```
<span>
     some text
     <img alt="" class="b61 emoji wa selectable-text invisible-space copyable-text" data-plain-text="" src="URL" style="background-position: -20px -20px;"/>
</span>
<span>
     more some text
     <img alt="" class="b62 emoji wa selectable-text invisible-space copyable-text" data-plain-text="" src="URL" style="background-position: -40px -40px;"/>
</span>
<span>
     blah-blah-blah
     <img alt="" class="b76 emoji wa selectable-text invisible-space copyable-text" data-plain-text="" src="URL" style="background-position: 0px -20px;"/>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need `.replaceWith`.

**Ex:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<span class="selectable-text invisible-space copyable-text" dir="ltr">
     some text
     <img alt="" class="b61 emoji wa selectable-text invisible-space copyable-text" data-plain-text="" src="URL" style="background-position: -20px -20px;"/>
     more some text
     <img alt="" class="b62 emoji wa selectable-text invisible-space copyable-text" data-plain-text="" src="URL" style="background-position: -40px -40px;"/>
     blah-blah-blah
     <img alt="" class="b76 emoji wa selectable-text invisible-space copyable-text" data-plain-text="" src="URL" style="background-position: 0px -20px;"/>
</span>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
for span in soup.findAll('span', {'class': 'selectable-text invisible-space copyable-text'}):
    for img in span.findAll("img"):
        img.replaceWith(r"<emoji>")
print(soup.prettify(formatter=None))
```

**Output:**

```
<span class="selectable-text invisible-space copyable-text" dir="ltr">
 some text
 <emoji>
 more some text
 <emoji>
 blah-blah-blah
 <emoji>
</span>
```